# Writing sigmoid function with input as (X * theta)

Tags: machine-learning, octave, logistic-regression

In Machine learning course, I am unable to visualize below input.

we have below equation in Logistic Regression :

[image]

We can write it in octave as below in `sigmoid.m`:

```
g = (1 ./ ( 1 + e.^(-z)));
```

Now, to calculate `costFUnction.m`, we are getting probability as:

```
h = sigmoid(X*theta);
```

From, the above picture, shouldn't it be:

```
h = sigmoid(theta'*X);
```

What am I missing here. I am newbie to ML so forgive me if I am missing something here.

Comment: What are the size(X) and size(theta) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll refer to [the material shared here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/supplement/WKgbA/multiple-features), you can see that

[image]

and what we want from `h(x)` is:

[image]

[image]

to visualize it:

```
X =  [ 1 x1 ; 1 x2 ; 1 x3;]
theta = [ t0 t1;]
X * theta
% will give  [ t0+(x1*t1) ; t0+(x2*t1) ; t0+(x3*t1) ; ]
```

where each row of above matrices represent separate hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing is to understand what every vector means. In most courses they talk about

```
    h = theta'* x
```

But here they use colum vectors so h is a scalar for one training example.
The vectorized notation tells you

```
    h = X * theta
```

Where X is a matrix all your training examples, where each example is a row and the features are colums. So m x n with m number of training examples and n number of features. You want h to give an output for each training example so you want a m x 1 matrix. You know that theta will be a n x 1 matrix as it is a theta for each feature and you have 1 model. If you do the second formula i wrote down at the top you will get as h a m x 1 matrix which is prefered.